# JavaScript regular expressions and sub-matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Why do Javascript sub-matches stop working when the `g` modifier is set?

```
var text = 'test test test test';

var result = text.match(/t(e)(s)t/);
// Result: ["test", "e", "s"]
```

The above works fine, `result[1]` is `"e"` and `result[2]` is `"s"`.

```
var result = text.match(/t(e)(s)t/g);
// Result: ["test", "test", "test", "test"]
```

The above ignores my capturing groups. Is the following the only valid solution?

```
var result = text.match(/test/g);
for (var i in result) {
    console.log(result[i].match(/t(e)(s)t/));
}
/* Result:
["test", "e", "s"]
["test", "e", "s"]
["test", "e", "s"]
["test", "e", "s"]
*/
```

**EDIT:**

I am back again to happily tell you that 10 years later you can now do this (.matchAll has been added to the spec)

```
let result = [...text.matchAll(/t(e)(s)t/g)];
```

Comment: Super nice with matchAll being able to do this :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am surprised to see that I am the first person to answer this question with the answer I was looking for 10 years ago (the answer did not exist yet). I also was hoping that the actual spec writers would have answered it before me ;).

**.matchAll** has already been added to a few browsers.

In modern javascript we can now accomplish this by just doing the following.

```
let result = [...text.matchAll(/t(e)(s)t/g)];
```

[**.matchAll spec**](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.matchall)

[**.matchAll docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

I now maintain an isomorphic javascript library that helps with a lot of this type of string parsing. You can check it out here: [string-saw](https://github.com/icodeforlove/string-saw). It assists in making .matchAll easier to use when using named capture groups.

An example would be

```
saw(text).matchAll(/t(e)(s)t/g)
```

Which outputs a more user-friendly array of matches, and if you want to get fancy you can throw in named capture groups and get an array of objects.

Comment: Languages evolve. So does _Javascript_. Glad to be the first upvoter of this gorgeous answer.

Comment: `String#matchAll` returns an iterator, not an array.

Answer (score 101):

Using `String`'s `match()` function won't return captured groups if the global modifier is set, as you found out.

In this case, you would want to use a `RegExp` object and call its `exec()` function. `String`'s `match()` is almost identical to `RegExp`'s `exec()` function…except in cases like these. If the global modifier is set, the normal `match()` function won't return captured groups, while `RegExp`'s `exec()` function will. (Noted [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regular-expressions-in-javascript-part-2/), among other places.)

Another catch to remember is that `exec()` doesn't return the matches in one big array—it keeps returning matches until it runs out, in which case it returns `null`.

So, for example, you could do something like this:

```
var pattern = /t(e)(s)t/g;  // Alternatively, "new RegExp('t(e)(s)t', 'g');"
var match;    

while (match = pattern.exec(text)) {
    // Do something with the match (["test", "e", "s"]) here...
}
```

Another thing to note is that `RegExp.prototype.exec()` and `RegExp.prototype.test()` execute the regular expression on the provided string and return the first result. Every sequential call will step through the result set updating `RegExp.prototype.lastIndex` based on the current position in the string.

Here's an example:
    // remember there are 4 matches in the example and pattern. lastIndex starts at 0

```
pattern.test(text); // pattern.lastIndex = 4
pattern.test(text); // pattern.lastIndex = 9
pattern.exec(text); // pattern.lastIndex = 14
pattern.exec(text); // pattern.lastIndex = 19

// if we were to call pattern.exec(text) again it would return null and reset the pattern.lastIndex to 0
while (var match = pattern.exec(text)) {
    // never gets run because we already traversed the string
    console.log(match);
}

pattern.test(text); // pattern.lastIndex = 4
pattern.test(text); // pattern.lastIndex = 9

// however we can reset the lastIndex and it will give us the ability to traverse the string from the start again or any specific position in the string
pattern.lastIndex = 0;

while (var match = pattern.exec(text)) {
    // outputs all matches
    console.log(match);
}
```

You can find information on how to use `RegExp` objects [on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (specifically, here's the documentation for [the `exec()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)).

Comment: using exec doesn't seem to listen to the g modifier, but it supports sub-matches/groups. So the result would be the first match (it basically ignores the g modifier)

Comment: Added a clarification about that—you have to call exec() repeatedly to get the multiple matches.

Comment: Not the most elegant solution.

i was expecting an output somewhat like this:

[
 ["test", "e", "s"],
 ["test", "e", "s"],
 ["test", "e", "s"],
 ["test", "e", "s"]
]

Comment: @htw this was a while back but i was rereading this and i found it weird that you did `new RegExp(/t(e)(s)t/g);` as an alt. wouldn't it be `new RegExp('t(e)(s)t', 'g');`

Comment: That makes more sense and seems more in-line with how the explicit RegExp constructor would actually be used. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Old, old question I know, but I had a need of this recently, and I whipped this up: `RegExp.prototype.execAll = function(s) { var r = [],m; while(m = this.exec(s)) r.push(m); return r; }`. With that, you can do: `/t(e)(s)t/.matchAll("test")` and get the results that @ChadScira was looking for.

Comment: Note for others bumping into another problem: If you use `.test()` before it, make sure you reset the lastIndex using `pattern.lastIndex = 0` before the `while` loop to get all the matches

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Thanks, updated answer in question detailing whats actually going on.

Comment: @ChadScira Great explanation, thanks! Hope it helps others too.

Comment: The g flag is not ignored.  It needs to be there, otherwise you'll get an infinite loop.  Found out the hard way here :)

Comment: Explicitly addresssing another corner case: If the regex has a capture group but global modifier _isn't_ being used, match() will return *the full match first*, then all substrings matching the capture. E.g. `'foobar'.match(/f(o)*(ba)/)` will return `["fooba", "o", "ba"]`.