# Getting all subgroups with a regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the string:

```
 © 2010 Women’s Flat Track Derby Association (WFTDA)
```

I want:

```
2010 -- Women's -- Flat
Women's -- Flat -- Track
Track -- Derby -- Association
```

I'm using regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\s([A-Z][a-z]*)\s([a-zA-Z]+)
```

It's only returning:

```
s -- Flat -- Track
```

Comment: Sorry - it's ultraedit JS, so probably javascript would work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem isn't straightforward, but to understand why, you need to understand how the regular expression engine operates on your string.

Let's consider the pattern `[a-z]{3}` (match 3 successive characters between a and z) on the target string `abcdef`. The engine starts from the left side of the string (before the `a`), and sees that `a` matches `[a-z]`, so it advances one position. Then, it sees that `b` matches `[a-z]` and advances again. Finally, it sees that `c` matches, advances again (to before `d`) and returns `abc` as a match.

If the engine is set up to return multiple matches, it will now try to match again, but it keeps its positional information (so, like above, it'll match and return `def`).

Because the engine has already moved past the `b` while matching `abc`, `bcd` will never be considered as a match. For this same reason, in your expression, once a group of words is matched, the engine will never consider words within the first match to be a part of the next one.

---

In order to get around this, you need to use capturing groups inside of [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to collect matching words that appear later in the string:

```js
var str = "2010 Women's Flat Track Derby Association",
    regex = /([a-z0-9']+)(?=\s+([a-z0-9']+)\s+([a-z0-9']+))/ig,
    match;

while (match = regex.exec(str))
{
    var group1 = match[1], group2 = match[2], group3 = match[3];
    console.log("Found match: " + group1 + " -- " + group2 + " -- " + group3);
}
```

This results in:

```
2010 -- Women's -- Flat
Women's -- Flat -- Track
Flat -- Track -- Derby
Track -- Derby -- Association
```

See this in action at http://jsfiddle.net/jRgXm/.

The regular expression searches for what you seem to be defining as a word `([a-z0-9']+)`, and captures it into subgroup 1, and then uses a lookahead (which is a zero-width assertion, so it doesn't advance the engine's cursor), that captures the next two words into subgroups 2 and 3.

**However**, if you are using the actual Javascript engine, you **must** `RegExp.exec` and loop over the results (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844001/javascript-regex-and-submatches) for a discussion of why) or use the new `matchAll` method (ES2020). I don't know how UltraEdit's engine is implemented, but hopefully it can do a global search and also collect subgroups.

Just for completeness, here's the example above using ES2020' `matchAll` (the first element in each returned array is the total match, then the subsequent elements are the capture groups):

```js
const str = "2010 Women's Flat Track Derby Association";
const regex = /([a-z0-9']+)(?=\s+([a-z0-9']+)\s+([a-z0-9']+))/ig;

console.log([...str.matchAll(regex)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using some generic regex tester, so I can't guarantee it will work for you but...

```
([A-Z0-9][\w’]+)\s([A-Z][\w]+)\s([A-Z][\w]+)
```

Three words starting with a number or capital letter followed by letters/numbers or that funky apostrophe, separated by spaces. Works for me.

Edit: I assume you can loop through, repeating the matcher in JS i've never used it.

Comment: Looks like it might be using Perl. Your shot got more, but not everything.

Comment: Won't work; regular expressions matches won't overlap. See my answer for more info.