# How do I quantify a group in Javascript's regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, quantifiers

Let's say I had a string "QQxaxbxcQQ", and I wanted to capture all groups of x followed by any character.  I also only want to search between the QQ's (the string may include other things in it).  I assumed this would have worked:

```
var matches = str.match(/QQ(x\w)+QQ/)
```

However, this only seems to return to me the last match (xc).  Can you point me in the right direction?

EDIT: the first version of my question was oversimplified.  Apologies to original responders.  Edited to make it closer to my actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

The + operator is greedy. `/(x\w)+/` should match the entire string `'xaxbxc'`, and the capturing group will contain the final value to match the `(x\w)` component. In this case `'xc'`. If you wish to capture each consecutive match, `/(x\w)+/` should instead be `/((?:x\w)+)/`. This moves the capturing group around the sequence instead of inside it. The `(?: )` represents a non-capturing group.

EDIT:

If you want every instance of `(x\w)`, not just consecutive instances, don't use the + operator or capturing groups. Just use a global regex: `/x\w/g`.

`'QQxaxbQQxcQQ'.match(/x\w/g)` yields `['xa, 'xb', 'xc']`.

`'QQxaxbQQxcQQ'.match(/((?:x\w)+)/)` yields `['xaxb', 'xaxb']`.

EDIT 2:

If you wish to search only between `QQ`s, a `split` should be the fastest method.
(Underscore helps a lot here.)

```
_.chain('xyQQxaxbQQxcQQxr'.split('QQ'))
.slice(1, -1)
.map(function (string) {
    return string.match(/x\w/g);
})
.flatten()
.compact()
.value()
```

yields ['xa', 'xb', 'xc']

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add `g` parameter at end of your regex. `g` flag returns an array containing all matches, in our case all matches of backreference `(x\w)`

In bold here: /QQ(x\w)+QQ/**g**

```
var matches = str.match(/QQ(x\w)+QQ/g)
```

matches is an array

look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/SZRSA/3/

Comment: Tell me, what does it return?

Comment: it is an array. BTW your question arrived before my update :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture all groups, use this :

```
var matches = str.match(/(x\w)/g)
```

output :

```
["xa", "xb", "xc"]
```

I made two changes :

- removed the `+` as you seem to want each x followed by one char
- added the `g` modifier to ask for all groups

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

---

EDIT : if what you want is to get your matches only when they're between QQ and QQ, you can do this :

```
var matches = str.split('QQ').filter(function(v,i){return i%2})
    .join(' ').match(/(x\w)/g)
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized I oversimplified my question.  I edited it, can you please have another look?

Comment: @user200814 I'm not sure I get why my answer doesn't work for you. Doesn't it give what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

```
'xaxbxc'.match(/x\w/g);
```

which returns

```
["xa", "xb", "xc"]
```

As the OP changed the question. now it's a duplication of [JavaScript regular expressions and sub-matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844001/javascript-regex-and-submatches).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps wrapping the repetition in a capturing group is what you want (capturing all instances of `x\w` concatenated together):

```
var matches = str.match(/QQ((x\w)+)QQ/)
```

This returns `"xaxbxc"` as `matches[1]`