# Javascript RegExp to find all occurences of a a quoted word in an array

Tags: javascript, regex

Given I have a sentence:

```
var testsentence = 'This "is" a wonderful "sentence" to "test" "stuff"';
```

How can I get an array like that?

```
var testarray = [ "is", "sentence", "test", "stuff" ]
```

**UPDATE**

I am using the Chromium console to try your response, but so far all the responses return:

```
[""is"", ""sentence"", ""test"", ""stuff""]
```

I don't want to have quotes in my matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture the quoted text, but not the quotes...note `match` won't return groups with the `g` modifier ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844001/javascript-regex-and-submatches)), so loop over the matches with something like:

```
var testsentence = 'This "is" a wonderful "sentence" to "test" "stuff"';
var pattern = /"([^"]+)"/g;
var match;
var testarray = [];
while(match = pattern.exec(testsentence)) {
    testarray.push(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: Is this really the quickest way? Hoped there was something simpler.

Comment: Not sure....if you don't save the regex in `var pattern` then it won't iterate matches during each loop. If you don't mind keeping the quotes, then others' solutions are more brief.

Answer (score 1):

```
(testsentence.match(/"\w+"/g) || []).map(function(w) {
    return w.slice(1, -1);
});
```

Comment: Only match quoted words. `He said "well, I won't do it" abruptly` wouldn't match.

Comment: @ClementHerreman: should that match? I dont think so. For a solution that does this see burning_LEGION's and RicardoLohmann's answers.

Comment: But I would have the quotes in the matches.

Comment: @user1680104: You'd have that with nearly all matching solutions. Just remove them from the results.

Comment: Thank you. So there really isn't something simpler? What if I had a similar task with a non-static pattern before? like `/sequencepart\d+"(stufftofind)"/`

Comment: Exactly. You'd have to use the `exec()` loop (see Ansons' answer) or matching + removing quotes, as JavaScript does not support [lookbehind regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as in `/(?<=")\w+(?=")/g`

Comment: How would I do something like `/sequencepart\d+"?(stufftofind)"?/` using Anson's answer? Is that possible?

Comment: I created [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850492/regular-expression-to-find-complex-markers), because it is.

Comment: @user1680104: Does Anson's code not work with that? It seems to be exactly the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
testsentence.match(/"([^"\s])+"/g)
```

should return everything that is quoted, and avoid things like `""`

Comment: No need for the grouping operator around the character class, btw

Answer (score 1):

```
testsentence.match(/"[^"]+"/g);
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cpRyT/)

Comment: But it has quotes in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
return testsentence.match(/".+?"/g);
```