# Regular Expression to find complex markers

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use JavaScript's regular expression something like this

```
/marker\d+"?(\w+)"?\s/gi
```

In a string like this:

```
IDoHaveMarker1"apple" IDoAlsoHaveAMarker352pear LastPointMakingmarker3134"foo"
```

And I want it to return an array like this:

```
[ "apple", "pear", "foo" ]
```

The quotes are to make clear they are strings. They shouldn't be in the result.

Comment: Just make the second `"` optional, too?

Comment: That's what I meant. Now how do I get the array?

Comment: Have you tried googling "javascript regex"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking about how to actually use the regex:

To get all captures of multiple (global) matches you have to use a loop and `exec` in JavaScript:

```
var regex = /marker\d+"?(\w+)/gi;
var result = [];
var match;
while (match = regex.exec(input)) {
    result.push(match[1]);
}
```

(Note that you can omit the trailing `"?\s?` if you are only interested in the capture, since they are optional anyway, so they don't affect the matched result.)

And no, `g` will not allow you to do all of that in one call. If you had omitted `g` then `exec` would return the same match every time.

As Blender mentioned, if you want to rule out things like `Marker13"something Marker14bar` (unmatched `"`) you need to use another capturing group and a backreference. Note that this will push your desired capture to index `2`:

```
var regex = /marker\d+("?)(\w+)\1/gi;
var result = [];
var match;
while (match = regex.exec(input)) {
    result.push(match[2]);
}
```

Comment: I'd use `/marker\d+("?)(\w+)\1/ig` as the regex, as it expects the quotes to come in pairs.

Comment: @Blender yeah, thought about that, but then I decided to remove the second `"` altogether.

Comment: You can stuff the matches in an array (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JLV6J/7/) and get the return result the OP is looking for.

Comment: @JasonSperske that's what I was referring to. you're right, maybe should've included the snippet with `push` instead

Comment: @m.buettner you are the second person I've seen in the last month who has a crazy high SO score in under 4 months.  I feel like I'm not using SO correctly :P  Probably has something to do with writing solid well thought out answers

Comment: @JasonSperske edited the answer. And it probably has something to do with finding the regex niche, where I can answer questions regarding any programming language. ;) plus, a certain proneness to getting addicted to my activities :D