# get detailed substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem i'm trying to solve, i have a javascript string (yes this is the string i have)

```
<div class="stories-title" onclick="fun(4,'this is test'); navigate(1)
```

What i want to achieve are the following points:

1) cut characters from start until the first ' character (cut the ' too)

---

2) cut characters from second ' character until the end of the string

---

3) put what's remaining in a variable

For example, the result of this example would be the string "this is test"

I would be very grateful if anyone have a solution.. Especially a simple one so i can understand it.

Thanks all in advance

Comment: Can you provide the full `<div>` element rather than cutting it off at the end?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split()` function:

```
var mystr = str.split("'")[1];
```

Comment: It should be noted that this only works for the first occurrence of `'(string)'`. That said, +1 for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
var newstr = str.replace(/[^']+'([^']+).*/,'$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to cut anything, you just want to match the string between the first `'` and the second `'` - see similar questions like [Javascript RegExp to find all occurences of a a quoted word in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13844105/1048572)

```
var string = "<div class=\"stories-title\" onclick=\"fun(4,'this is test'); navigate(1)";
var m = string.match(/'(.+?)'/);
if (m)
    return m[1]; // the matching group
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions

```
/\'(.+)\'/
```

http://rubular.com/r/RcVmejJOmU

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the work yourself:

```
    var str = "<div class=\"stories-title\" onclick=\"fun(4,'this is test'); navigate(1)";

    var newstr = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '\'') {
            while (str[++i] != '\'') {
                newstr += str[i];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```