# Why does this non-capturing group capture?

Tags: javascript, regex, css-selectors, pattern-matching

Applying this regex pattern:

```
/(?:(^| |\>|\+))+([a-z\-\_]+)/gi
```

to this string:

```
body.test ol+li ol > li #foobar p>span a[href=*]
```

I get these matches, comma separated:

```
body, ol,+li, ol, > li, p,>span, a
```

Why do some matches have the leading space , `>` and `+` sign? I'd expect this part of my regex `(?:(^| |\>|\+))` to match those signs, but not capture them.

Edit: I am trying to match html tags and css selectors contributing to css specificity of an css selector. Thus I want to match each `li` or `span` or so forth on its own, without the `+` or `>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capturing is not the same as matching. Since you're specifying the combinators in your pattern, they will be picked up by the matcher, regardless of whether they're captured or non-captured.

To capture, you need to `exec()` your regular expression on the string and loop through the results, which *will* contain your capture groups. I've also cleaned up your pattern and modified it so it doesn't capture unnecessarily and will recognize [the general sibling combinator `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators):

```
var sel = "body.test ol+li ol > li #foobar p>span a[href=*]";
var re = /(?:^| |>|\+|~)+([a-z_-]+)/gi;
var matches = [], m;

while (m = re.exec(sel)) {
    matches.push(m[1]);
}
```

You will then obtain the expected matches:

```
body, ol, li, ol, li, p, span, a
```

Comment: Perfect explanation and answer. Debugging the content of `m` in the while loop helped me understand what is going on. I am using it in [a small javascript module that calculates css specifity](https://github.com/johannesneumeier/css-specifity/blob/master/specifity.js).

Comment: @kontur: You may want to rename it - the correct spelling is "specificity" (that's "specific" + "ity") :)

Answer (score 2):

The inner bracket in `(?:(^| |\>|\+))` is creating a captured group. You can just make it non-capturing too, and I think, you should have the `+`  quantifier inside the outer bracket:

```
/(?:(?:^| |\>|\+)+)([a-z\-\_]+)/gi
```

Also, you can use a character class instead to avoid having those `pipes` in between, and also you won't then need to escape `>` and `+`. But remember, not to use `caret(^)` at the beginning of the character class, else it will negate everything:

```
/(?:[ >+^]+)([a-z_-]+)/gi
```

You don't need to escape `-` and `_` in a character class. Just use the `-` at the end, and all is fine.

Comment: Hm, weird, when trying to figure out what's wrong I tried that on this online regex tester: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ and it seems to be faulty - it still shows the matches with the `+` etc. Trying the same on http://rubular.com/ your suggestion works. Problem solved, should avoid the first regexp tool then. Also thanks for your suggestion about the character class!

Comment: `(?:^|[ >+])` this works, seems like the `^` inside the class would indicate the negation, rather than the line beginning.

Comment: @kontur.. No, when you use `^` at the beginning, only then it denotes negation. Else it is just the `^` only. Anyways, I have updated the first regex, you needed to use nested non-capturing group there since you were using quantifier.

Comment: great insights here, thanks! Could there be some difference in regex handling here? The online javascript regex tool as well as my firefox seem to still match those `+` signs, yet the ruby regex online tool does not match them. Or am I missing something here? Also, using your regexp `(?:[ >+^]+)([a-z_-]+)` at http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ does not match the starting `body` tag, which is why I thought the `^` needs to be outside the group.

Comment: regex.larsolavtorvik.com on the javascript tab, as well as Firefox.

Comment: @kontur.. What is your exact requirement?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24231/discussion-between-kontur-and-rohit-jain)

Comment: @kontur.. Try out this: - `(((?![ >+^]).)+)`

Answer (score 0):

You have capturing group here: `(^| |\>|\+)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two capturing groups, `(^| |\>|\+)` and `([a-z\-\_]+)` - the first one directly inside of a non-capturing group. Just remove it:

```
/(?:^| |>|\+)+([a-z_-]+)/gi
```

On how to get the captured groups while repeatedly (*global*) matching see [JavaScript regular expressions and sub-matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/844001/1048572). Btw, you could as well try to use `.split(/[ >+]+/)` or `.match(/[^ >+]+/g)`.

Comment: @RohitJain has pointed this out already. Somehow though I still get matches that include the `+` and `>` signs, as well as the spaces.

Comment: The whole match of course does include all the characters. The first (and only) capturing group will not. How do you apply the regex?

Comment: `"body, ol,+li, ol, > li, p,>span, a".match(/(?:(^| |\>|\+))+([a-z\-\_]+)/gi);`

Comment: @kontur: That's matching, not capturing. Matching always picks up a subpattern whether or not you're capturing it.

Comment: @BoltClock yes, I seemed to miss that subtle difference - @RohitJain explained it to me in chat. It still seems very weird that `"Lorem ipsum dol solor".match(/(?: )/gi)` would *match* three empty spaces. Really a bit puzzling. How can I access *captured* as opposed to *matched* groups in javascript?

Comment: @kontur: I've posted an answer. (Actually two, but one had the completely unrealistic assumption that you had to use matching instead of trying to capture - that's already deleted.)