# Why doesn't String.match() produce expected results when a global flag is present?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying this match

```
'/links/51f5382e7b7993e335000015'.match(/^\/links\/([0-9a-f]{24})$/g)
```

and got:

```
['/links/51f5382e7b7993e335000015']
```

while I was expecting:

```
['/links/51f5382e7b7993e335000015', '51f5382e7b7993e335000015']
```

I had no luck until I removed the global flag, which I did not think would impact results my results!

With the global flag removed,

```
'/links/51f5382e7b7993e335000015'.match(/^\/links\/([0-9a-f]{24})$/)
```

produced:

```
[ '/links/51f5382e7b7993e335000015',
  '51f5382e7b7993e335000015',
  index: 0,
  input: '/links/51f5382e7b7993e335000015' ]
```

which is cool, but reading the docs I can't figure out:

- Why the first form didn't work
- Why the global flag interfered with the `()` matching
- How to get my expected result without the `index` and `input` properties

On [JavaScript Regex and Submatches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/844049/741970) the top answer says:

> Using String's match() function won't return captured groups if the global modifier is set, as you found out.

However,

```
> 'fofoofooofoooo'.match(/f(o+)/g) 
["fo", "foo", "fooo", "foooo"]
```

seems to produce captured groups just fine.

Thank you.

Comment: I edited the question to address the possible duplicate issue.

Comment: It's a duplicate, but +1 for "I tried..., I got..., I was expecting...".  I wish more questions were like this.

Comment: Hah! Thanks... I will look again, and more carefully, at the linked page.

Comment: @PavelAnossov My bad, I meant to include the (). Please see now. Works the same! Is that not a captured group, despite the ()?

Comment: The edited last example isn't putting captured groups in the output, it is including different matches of the whole pattern.

Comment: @dimadima: the thing is, without `g` String.match produces "first match and its captured groups", with `g` it produces "all matches of the entire pattern".

Comment: @PavelAnossov, ah, I understand, thank you: The resulting array can only represent one or the other: either (i) the first match and its captured groups, OR (ii) all matches of the pattern. So `g` necessitates that the result array is of the latter form.

Comment: I voted to close this as, indeed, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7df7sf4x%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) for match method:

> If the global flag (g) is not set, **Element zero of the array contains the entire match, while elements 1 through n contain any submatches.** This behavior is the same as the behavior of the exec Method (Regular Expression) (JavaScript) when the global flag is not set. If the global flag is set, **elements 0 through n contain all matches that occurred.**

Emphasis mine.

So, in your **1st case**:

```
'/links/51f5382e7b7993e335000015'.match(/^\/links\/([0-9a-f]{24})$/g)
```

Since `/g` modifier is set, it will return just the complete matches that occurred, and not the submatches. That is why you just got an array with single element. As there is only 1 match for that regex.

**2nd case**:

```
'/links/51f5382e7b7993e335000015'.match(/^\/links\/([0-9a-f]{24})$/)
```

`/g` modifier is not set. So the array contains the complete match at `0th` index. And further elements (1st index) in array are submatches - in this case, 1st capture group.

---

As for your **last example**:

```
'fofoofooofoooo'.match(/f(o+)/g)
```

Again, since `/g` modifier is set, it will return all the matches from the string, and not the submatches. So, in the string, the regex `f(o+)` matches 4 times:

```
fo    - 1st complete match (sub-match 'o' in 1st captured group ignored)
foo   - 2nd complete match (sub-match 'oo' ignored)
fooo  - 3rd complete match (sub-match 'ooo' ignored)
foooo - 4th complete match (sub-match 'oooo' ignored)
```

If you use the last regex without `/g` modifier, you would get each submatch as separate element, for the first match. Try:

```
'fofoofooofoooo'.match(/f(o+)/)
```

You will get:

```
["fo", "o"]  // With index and input element of course.
```

Without `/g` it just stops after first match (`fo`), and returns the entire match and sub-matches.

Comment: Thank you very much for this Rohit! Wow, really appreciate this answer.

Comment: Rohit: Actually, `'fofoofooofoooo'.match(/f(o+)/)` produces `['fo', 'o', index: 0, input: 'fofoofooofoooo']`. I believe this is because there is no backtracking that goes on.

Comment: @dimadima. Oh! So, it just returns the first match and the submatch. I just guessed that output. Hmm, it's clear, since global flag is not set, it will not try to match more than once.

Comment: Yep, which is actually simpler and makes sense. I'm glad that's the real result :).

Comment: @dimadima. Edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), if the `g` flag is not specified it returns the same results as [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Fexec), which returns an array including items for capturing parentheses.

If the `g` flag is specified it returns an array containing all matches.

This description is consistent with the examples in the question, but your two examples are sort of apples with oranges:

- Your "links" regex matches the entire input string once, possibly with one captured group depending on the flag.
- Your `/f(o+)/g` regex matches several substrings in the input.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and your clarification of my example