# How to extract the value of a parameter in Javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var text = "{templateUrl: 'conversations/conversations.tpl.html',";
var result = text.match(/templateUrl:(\s*['"]\S*['"])/g);
```

I want result to be 'conversations/conversations.tpl.html' but I am getting "templateUrl: 'conversations/conversations.tpl.html'".

I have checked it here: http://regex101.com/r/uW1vY6 and it does what I expect, but not in the console or in a real program.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Regex and Submatches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844001/javascript-regex-and-submatches)

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly how you get the matched groups from the regex

```
var text = "{templateUrl: 'conversations/conversations.tpl.html',";
var myRegexp = /templateUrl:(\s*['"]\S*['"])/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(text);
alert(match[1]);
```

try this

```
var text = "{templateUrl: 'conversations/conversations.tpl.html',";
var result = text.match(/\'(.*)\'/)[0];
console.log(result);
```