# Simple Regex Pattern Matching

Tags: javascript, php, regex, vb.net, preg-match

Here's my pattern

```
<a href="(.*?)" onmousedown="test\(\)">
```

Here's the source

```
<tags><tags><a href="http://google.com" onmousedown="test()"></tags></tags>
```

If I use that pattern, I get this result:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onmousedown="test()">
```

What I want to get is just

```
http://google.com
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: why not `'<tags><tags><a href="http://google.com" onmousedown="test()"></tags></tags>'.match(/<a href="(.*?)" onmousedown="test\(\)">/)[1]` - Not a fan of parsing HTML using regex... could always lead to unexpected results

Comment: In the `preg_match` documentation http://php.net/preg_match, it will show you how to access subpattern matches.

Comment: If this is PHP, why not use [`DomDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or Microsoft.mshtml for vb.net. I mean, if you're getting the data from a website, parsing would be a better route. However, if you're simply getting one or two tags, you can still just explode by `href="` and `" `.

Comment: Possible a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844001/javascript-regex-and-submatches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844001/javascript-regex-and-submatches) if you are using String's match() with global modifier

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the regex slightly(adding `.*` at both ends) so that it fits with both the below examples.

```
var regex = /.*?<a href="([^">]*)" onmousedown="test\(\)">.*/; 
var input = '<tags><tags><a href="http://google.com" onmousedown="test()"></tags></tags>';
```

**Approach#1:** Using regex replace. In this case this is matching the whole string with the pattern and replace it with only the first captured group(`$1`).

```
url1 = input.replace(regex, "$1");
alert(url1)
```

**Approach#2:** Using regex matching with the input string and the pattern and after that only picking the first captured group(`[1]`).

```
url2 = regex.exec(input)[1];
alert(url2);
```

In both cases the output will be the url from `href` tag.