# Select everything between not starting with but ending with

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am trying to select some names with JS but I can figure out how. I found 3 solution here but still could not get it to work:

I would like to select word that DOESN'T start with `.` and HAS to end with `{`

Here is what I have:
`\b(?!\.)[\w\-]+(?=\s*{)\b`

Also tried: `^(?!\.)[\w\-]+(?=\s*:)`

#### Example:

.test { }

**test** { } <--- Select this test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to match `-^!foo {}`, use `(?:\s|^)([^\s\.]+(?=\s*\{))`.

If you wish to only match `foo {}`, use `(?:[^\w\.]|^)([^\W\.]+(?=\s*\{))`.

```js
var pattern1 = /(?:\s|^)([^\s\.]+(?=\s*\{))/gm,
    pattern2 = /(?:[^\w\.]|^)([^\W\.]+(?=\s*\{))/gm,
    text = ".foo{}  bar {} !!baz{} ..-boom  {}",
    match;

console.log('First pattern:');
while (match = pattern1.exec(text)) {
  console.log(match[1]); // Prints "bar", "!!baz"
}

console.log('Second pattern:');
while (match = pattern2.exec(text)) {
  console.log(match[1]); // Prints "bar", "baz", "boom"
}
```

**Explanation of the first regex:**

1. We expect the leading position before your word to either be the start
   of the line `^` or whitespace `\s`.
2. The word itself consists of repeated non-whitespace characters that
   are not dots `[^\s\.]`.
3. The word must be followed by a `{`, for which we use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
   via `(?=\{)`.

JavaScript's regex engine doesn't support [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so you have to use a non-capturing group `(?:...)` to match the leading position before your word.

See [JavaScript regular expressions and sub-matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844001/javascript-regular-expressions-and-sub-matches) for an explanation of how to access capturing groups

See https://regex101.com/r/bT8sE5/5 for a live demo of the regex with further explanation.

Comment: This is what I was looking for... Can you please explain how you did it, because as I can see you negated the .

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanation. Can you please make a simple edit here in comment how would I make an exaction. For example if I find a keyword after `{` don't select it. `test { keyword` this should not be selected. I already know the key word.. It's keywords buy nevermind.. What I tried `^(?!.*keyword$)([^\S\.\#]|^)([^\s.\#(]+(?=\{))+$`

Comment: so you want `test{}` to match, but `test{keyword}` should not match? Then append `(?!\{keyword)` to the first regex in this answer (a negative lookahead). If you also would like to match `test {}` but not `test { keyword` (note the spaces) use `(?:\s|^)([^\s\.]+(?=\s*\{))(?!\s*\{\s*keyword)`

Comment: Right, when there is a special keyword after `{` exclude it.

`class{ignore  <other stuff> }` not selecter

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

`([^\w\.]|^)(\w+\{)`

It's basically saying anything at the start of the line, or beginning with a nonword / nondot character.

It's tricky to do with \b since it matches after the dot quite happily. You can possibly get it to work with the negative lookahead but it's pretty funky stuff at this point :)

Comment: This version would not work if a class had a separator, for example `test-sep {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this: `^.*\.(\w+\{\}){1}.*$`

Explanation:

- `^` is the beginning of the string
- `.*` matches everything behind the dot (`.`)
- `(\w+\{\})*` the capture group matches the word and the brackets after it *(for example **test{}**}* zero or more times
- `.*` matches everything after the word
- `$` is the end of the string

So for the input: `sadasdas.test{}daasdasdasdasd` it will match `test{}`

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/hE4uY4/1

Comment: Nice try but I think you miss understood me, I want to select only `test` without a dot. Basically with a string has a dot in front ignore it, but if it doesn't check if it ends with `:`

Answer (score 0):

The following works in relation to http://regexr.com/
You can test it there.

```
/(?![\s])(^[^.]([\S]+)[{}][\s])/igm
```