# Regex do not match content but whole searched string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm using this regex to match an "href" attribute in a `<a>` tag:

```
var href_matches = postRep.match(/href="(.*?)"/g);
```

The regex matches correctly the href except it returns the whole "href=http:example.com" string.
How do I manage to get only the href value (eg. "example.com")?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript regular expressions and sub-matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844001/javascript-regular-expressions-and-sub-matches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either run `exec()` on the regex :

```
var url_match = /href="(.*?)"/g.exec(postRep);
```

or remove the global flag

```
var url_match = postRep.match(/href="(.*?)"/);
```

> Using String's match() function won't return captured groups if the
>   global modifier is set.

Comment: I went with the "exec" solution above and looped each result. Really thanks for that, Flint! It worked

Answer (score 1):

Just another idea.

You can try something like this function:

```
function getHrefs(inputString) {
    var out = [];
    inputString.replace(/\bhref\b=['"]([^'"]+)['"]/gi, function(result, backreference) {
        out.push(backreference);
        return '';
    });
    return out;
}
```

Improved solution (much shortest):

```
function getHrefs(inputString) {
    return (inputString.match(/\bhref\b=['"][^'"]+(?=['"])/gi) || []).map(s => s.replace(/^href=["']/,""));
}
```

Edit:

There is other option - exec. But with exec you will need loop to get all matches (if you need this).

Comment: Thanks for this one! But I think the "exec" solution is more straightforward for my needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex lookbehinds to check if the "href=" is there without actually including it in the match.
For example, the regex `(?<=href=)example\.com` applied to `href=example.com` should only match `example.com`.

EDIT:
This method only works in languages that support regex lookbehinds. Javascript doesn't support this feature. (thanks to Georgi Naumov for pointing this out)

Comment: JavaScript regex engine don't support lookbehind.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to just use javascript to trim off the "href=" after it gets matched?

Comment: Yes. My second solution is similar. There is lookahead but unfortunately we don't have lookbehind.